# (Re) MOSFET as LED current regulator

Tags: led

I would like to use a MOSFET LED Current regulator to source 700mA in 7X Cree XM-L High Power LEDS in series. To test my circuit, i use my workbench powersupply. The image of my circuit is in attaced file
I set voltage at 20V and i use FQPF2N80 as MOSFET Q2 and BC337 as Q1.
But i don't understand, i expected a voltage aroud 0.5V -0.6V at R2, and i obtain only 0.260V? with a current of 330mA? Maybe my input voltage is not enough? Could you help me?
Regards,[image]

Comment: What is the forward voltage of the LEDs? Link to datasheet?

Comment: Realize that Q2 may get really hot. I don't recommend running cases above 70 degC. From about 0.5 - 1.0 W you might get away with a few square inches of copper on your PWB. More than 1 W you probably need a larger heatsink.

Comment: Your MOSFET has a max RDSon of 6.3 Ohms with 10 Vgs. You'll need to add in that 4.4 V drop to all the other overhead you have to plan for. Just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe my input voltage is not enough?

It looks like it.

[image]

*Table 1. From the [datasheet](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampXML-11E.pdf).*

With 2.9 V typical V<sub>f</sub> and 3.5 V max you would require between 20.3 V and 24.5 V across the LEDs and another couple of volts across Q2 and R2.

Solution:

- Increase the supply voltage.
- Take out two LEDs.

Simple tests:

- Measure the current.
- Measure again while shorting out two of the LEDs.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to supress one or two Leds because i use a Cree MPCB equipped with 7x Cree XML lamp in series. But according to Cree XML Datasheet, Vf is arund 2.9V for a current of 700mA.

Comment: 2.9 V is what I stated in my answer. Why are you stating it in the comment?

Comment: @marcounet - 2.9V is for each LED. Typical: 2.9V * 7 = 20.3V.  Max: 3.5V * 7 = 24.5V. You need Vin > ~26V for reliable operation at 700mA.

Comment: @Mattman944 The MOSFET will drop some more volts. Look at its max RDSon. So even *more* Vin.

Comment: @jonk - Crap, I shouldn't have assumed, I just saw the big package and assumed a few tenths of an ohm. Vin needs to be ~ 30V!

Comment: @Mattman944 I hate mosfets. Except when I love them. They are really bad when driven by an opamp output (oscillations, which can be snubbed with a series resistor and also with a cap from output back to (-) input.) I can add a zero right on top of the HF pole to fix it, but then I have to do a new calibration every time I build one. So I just don't like them much. Plus, they cost a lot more than they should (in my mind.) Here, I'd use a D44H11 BJT instead. The recomb current at the base would be less than 10 mA and easily affordable. Those thoughts caused me to "go look at the mosfet sheet."

Answer (score 1):

I thought your MOSFET must be junk - but it's not - it's a lovely device when used properly .
BUT it is the utterly wrong one for this task.
With an Rdson of 6.3 Ohms typical you are dropping 4V+ at 700 mA.
The FET has a Vdsmax of 800 V !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.
Use a FET with Rdson in the 10-50 milliohm range - there are many.

When reading datasheets (LED or other) you cannot use typical values for design.
You MUST use worst case values or select-on-test.

With 7 LEDS in series you can HOPE that they average out, but if they are from the same production batch they may well be closely matched.

Even at the typical 2.9V you only have 20 - (7 x 2.9) = 20.3V = MINUS 0.3V headroom for the current source. Q1 needs about 0.65V say, Q2 with a sensible FET may need 0.1V -
**so** you have about 1V too little voltage.

Solution:

1. Replace MOSFEt
2. Increase Vin
3. If you cannot increase Vin then shorting out one LED is the only available option.

[XM-L datasheet](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampXML-11E.pdf)

[FQPF2N80 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQPF2N80-D.pdf)